# Staying outside US with green card for 5 months in the year that I qualify for US citizenship

Tags: citizenship, greencard

Since I got my green card I have never stayed outside of the US for more than 6 months and 60% of the year, in the last 4 years, I stayed in the US.

This coming November, I can apply for US citizenship.

My question is that since this is the last year of my 5-year residency with a green card, if I stay outside the US for 5 months, will this negatively impact my citizenship?

During my citizenship interview, will I get asked why I did not stay the entire year and left for 5 months? Will I get asked to stay 5 more months after my interview and then re-apply for citizenship?

I heard that in the last year, I should be completely in the US to show the completed transition to US residency.

My 5-year continuous residency will be on `02/15/2025` and I can file my citizenship 90 days before that on `11/17/2024`. This means I have to reside in the US 3 months before my filing date, which is `08/17/2024`. Am I allowed to leave the country (for less than 6 months) after I filed the application?

Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the last of the 5 years and the other years. To naturalize under the 5-year rule, you need to meet the [continuous residence requirement](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-d-chapter-3) (continuous residence for the last 5 years, and continue to have continuous residence until naturalization) and the [physical presence requirement](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-d-chapter-4) (physically present in the US for half of those 5 years, i.e. 30 months). An absence of less than 6 months should generally not interrupt continuous residence. As for the physical presence test, you will need to see if you will still have 30 months out of the last 5 years after your 5-month absence.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I satisfy all the continuous residency and physical presence requirements. My 5-year continuous residency will be on `02/15/2025` and I can file my citizenship 90 days before that on `11/17/2024`. This means I have to reside in the US 3 months before my filing date, which is `08/17/2024`. Am I allowed to leave the country (for less than 6 months) after I filed the application and only stay in the US from `08/17/2024` to `11/17/2024`?

Comment: @shashashamti2008: Yes. And there is no requirement that you be continuously physically present in the US for the 3 months before you file. You just need to have been *residing* in the state you file from for 3 months. You can take brief vacations elsewhere without affecting your residence.

Comment: This link you sent me https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-d-chapter-3 says "An applicant must also establish that he or she has resided in the state or service district having jurisdiction over the application for 3 months prior to filing.". Doesn't this mean I have to be in the US 3 months before filing?

Comment: @shashashamti2008: No, residing there doesn't mean you have to be physically there all the time.